# Difficulty Removing Installation Files -- I think

Tags: 18.04, updates, 32-bit, google

While refreshing updates, this is the notice at the end. How shall I remove or uninstall the culprit software?

```
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' 
as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease'
doesn't support architecture 'i386', 
E:Repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic-updates Release' changed its 
'Suite' value from 'bionic' to 'bionic-updates',
E:Repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic-updates Release' changed its 'Codename' 
value from 'bionic' to 'bionic-updates'
```

I have a 64 bit operating system.

Ratchet M.

Comment: I can understand part of it, as I am just beginning. I barely know enough to just get by. Over time, hopefully, these answers will sink in, but I might  need to sleep on it for awhile. I'm wondering if my new Mint Tessa had the Google World software to download and I accidentally checked off something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To fix:

```
W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' 
as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease'
doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

---

Edit two files:

**`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list`**

And change:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

To:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

**`sudo -H gedit /etc/cron.daily/google-earth-pro`**

And change:

```
REPOCONFIG="deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"
```

To:

```
REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"
```

---

## To fix:

```
E:Repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic-updates Release' changed its 
'Suite' value from 'bionic' to 'bionic-updates',
E:Repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic-updates Release' changed its 'Codename' 
value from 'bionic' to 'bionic-updates'
```

---

`cd /etc/apt` # change directory

`grep -i ddebs.ubuntu.com sources.list` # search this .list file

`grep -i ddebs.ubuntu.com sources.list.d/*.list` # search other .list files

`sudo -H gedit found_path/found_filename.list` # edit the found .list file

Find the line that contains `ddebs.ubuntu.com` and change `bionic` to `bionic-updates`